# SQL DB Power Shell Connection Code error I don't understand

Tags: sql, database, powershell, syntax, syntax-error

So I have a peice of code that I'm using to try to write to the database but I keep getting an error at the bottom that makes no sense. everything seems to work interdependantly but executing the code is just... no.

I pulled this db query ps code from 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckwoody/2009/04/13/run-a-sql-server-command-from-powershell-without-the-sql-server-provider/

here is the code, the error is below the Close().

I'm totally lose. Help?

```
        $strserver = "1sl-den-db03"
$strdatabase = "reporting"
$strusername = "belamiinc\PSscripts"
#you can get convert pass by "p@ssw0rdt3xt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Users\daniel.williams\Documents\Scriptcred.txt"
$strpassword = Get-Content "C:\Users\daniel.williams\Documents\Scriptcred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
#$strQuery = "
#INSERT INTO EventLog (SourceID, Started, Completed, Result, Context, Machine)
#SELECT (50, null, null, 'error undefined query','query run outside of manufacturer','1sl-den-db03')
#"
$strQuery = "
insert into [reporting].[dbo].[password] (Username, Password)
select (test, testpw)
"


# Create and open a database connection
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$strserver;database=$strdatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=$strusername; password=$strpassword"


#Create a command object
$sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$sqlCommand.CommandText = $strQuery

$sqlConnection.Open()

#Execute the Command
$sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

$sqlConnection.Close()
```

The error is:

```
PS C:\Windows> Y:\DEPT - IT\Scripting\PSConnecttoSQL.ps1
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near ','."
At Y:\DEPT - IT\Scripting\PSConnecttoSQL.ps1:27 char:1
+ $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Where does `select (test, testpw)` in your insert statement come from? That's part of the problem with your query.

Comment: If `test` and `testpw` are meant to be text then you should write it lik this: `select 'test', 'testpw'` or `values('test', 'testpw')`. Take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a reader for an  `INSERT` command. Change this line:

```
 $sqlReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Into:

```
 $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

More about [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Same error. Other thoughts?

`PS C:\Windows> Y:\DEPT - IT\Scripting\PSConnecttoSQL.ps1
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near ','."
At Y:\DEPT - IT\Scripting\PSConnecttoSQL.ps1:21 char:1
+ $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException`

Comment: There, I have corrected my answer. You shoukd check your insert statement as well. You have no closing <kbd>'</kbd>  between `..., 'error` and `, undefined`.

Comment: Sigh. Still the same thing. I did modify the insert statement. Thanks for seeing that.

I modified my code as well. It now 1) Hits a table I know isn't locked (the documentation said sqlerror can mean locked tables) and 2) opens the connection after I define the command because that's how they do it in the documentation example (though the order in which I define variables shouldn't matter)